# Set CFBundleDisplayName app name for cordova app on iOS (using fastlane)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, fastlane

I have trouble setting the correct app name below the icon for a Cordova iOS app.
I use [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/cli/index.html#create-the-app), [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools), [match](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/match) and [gym](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym) to create the build.

To create a Cordova project I do:

```
cordova create cordova-dir cordova.app.id cordova-appName
```

In the generated `Info.plist` file it says:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
```

`gym` command in `Fastfile` file is:

```
gym(
  project: "./cordova-dir/platforms/ios/cordova-appName.xcodeproj",
  scheme: "cordova-appName",
  use_legacy_build_api: "true",
  export_method: "enterprise",
  codesigning_identity: "iPhone Distribution: My Company Limited"
)
```

The generated command is:

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -scheme 'cordova-appName' -project './build-cordova/platforms/ios/cordova-appName.xcodeproj' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath '/private/var/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-03-29/cordova-appName 2016-03-29 16.20.06.xcarchive' archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Distribution: My Company Limited' | tee /private/var/user/Library/Logs/gym/cordova-appName-cordova-appName.log | xcpretty
```

The `ipa file` is called `cordova.app.id.ipa`
The displayed name on the device below the icon later is `cordova.app.id`, not `cordova-appName`.

I'm confused what actually sets the name of an app. I don't want to involve opening xcode in this at all. I hope one of the involved settings/options is able to set the correct name.
HockeyApp is used to distribute the app.

Comment: It looks like that the name which is correctly set with Cordova and also used in a manual build with xcode somehow is getting lost when using gym. Will dig a bit more.

Comment: That was a nice one, looks like I just set one wrong environment variable during the build. Hate when that happens.